# Android how to put and retrieve data from Notification

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I'm writing android messenger. When the app is minimized and some contact writes me, notification is thrown successfully. if two contacts write, each message is shown in different box. [image]

So I need to put and then get contact id..

here is my code in application, from where notification is thrown:

```
private void showNotification(Message m) {
    Contact temp = dbHelper.getContact(m.getPersonID());

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChatActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("prsID", m.getPersonID());
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);


    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    builder.setTicker("Messenger: New Message");
    builder.setContentTitle(temp.getName());
    builder.setContentText(m.getMessage());
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);


    if (temp.hasImage()){
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(temp.getImageByteArr(), 0, temp.getImageByteArr().length);
        builder.setLargeIcon(bmp);
    }

    Notification noti = builder.setContentIntent(pIntent).build();
    noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(temp.getId(), noti); 

}
```

and here is code in ChatActivity, where I'm trying to retrieve contact id:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (this.guest != null){
        int prsid = getIntent().getIntExtra("prsID", -1);
        if (prsid != -1){
            this.guest = this.messageLoader.getContact(prsid);
            ContactForChat.getInstance().setContact(this.guest.getId());
        } else {
            this.guest = this.messageLoader.getContact(this.guest.getId());
            ContactForChat.getInstance().setCurrentID(this.guest.getId());
        }
        this.guest.setNewMessage(false);
        this.messageLoader.updateContact(guest);
    }

    if (this.messageLoader != null)
        this.messageLoader.chatOnPause(false);
}
```

but int prsid = getIntent().getIntExtra("prsID", -1); always returns -1

[image]

anybody can help me? how to do it correctly?
thank you in advance

**UPDATE**

in fact, i guess getIntent() returns null:
[image]

**SOLUTION**

in ChatActivity I had to override a method (both, a and ab has correct value in it):

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    Bundle a = intent.getExtras();
    int ab = a.getInt("prsID");
    int b = intent.getIntExtra("prsID", -1);
}
```

Comment: I found solution: I had to override: ` protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)`  and code inside looks like: ` super.onNewIntent(intent);
  Bundle a = intent.getExtras();
  int ab = a.getInt("prsID"); `

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna take a stab and guess that `m.getPersonID()` returns a long and not an int? So you need to use `getIntent().getLongExtra("prsID", -1);`

Comment: public class Message {
 ...
 private int personID;
...
public int getPersonID() {
  return personID;
 }
....

Comment: Have you debugged your `onResume` method to see what `getIntent().getExtras()` returns?

Comment: does android manifest need soecial tags for chatActivity? mine says that:
 <activity
            android:name="com.example.freeunichat.ui.ChatActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

Comment: No you don't need any extra tags

Answer (score 0):

In your `showNotification` method, make the first blank line `Log.v("NOTIFICATION", "id = " + m.getPersonID());` and make sure it's actually set to something other than -1 when you add it to the extras. Additionally, make sure that the return type of `m.getPersonID()` is an `int`, and not a `long`, `double`, or some other number.

Comment: I've debugged it and it really adds correct personID and it is int

Answer (score -1):

To differentiate notification you can

You can use this

```
mManager.notify(0, notification); to  mManager.notify((int) when, notification);
```

where

```
 long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Comment: why negative comment any reason?

Comment: not me :) but anyway, my question wasn't about differentiating notifications. as you can see in main question: notificationManager.notify(temp.getId(), noti);  so every new message notification from different contacts, have different id-s